# Search product name in List<Product>

Tags: c#, list, search

The function implements the search of a product in the list. I am getting an error in the return type inside the if loop. What should be the return type if the product 
is found and what should be the return type if the productname is not found??The value should be returned to which variable in main() method??

```
namespace Sample
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    } 

    class Program
    {
        public static Product SearchProductsByName(string ProductsName, List<Product> products)
        {
            Product pd;
            pd= new Product();
            foreach (Product rs in products)
            {
                if (ProductsName == rs.Name)
                {
                    return pd;
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product res=new Product();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the product");
        string pname = Console.ReadLine();
        res=SearchRestaurantsByName(pname , products);
    }
```

Comment: It's most common to return `null` when there is no matching item in the list

Comment: This question sure needs more answers lol.

Answer (score 6):

Put it like that:

```
public static Product SearchProductsByName(string ProductsName, List products) {
  foreach (Product rs in products) 
    if (ProductsName == rs.Name)
      return rs; // <- The product found

  return null; // <- There's no such a product in the list
}
```

EDIT: As for `Main` method, something like that is expected:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  // You should declare and fill in the products list
  // where you'll be looking for the product
  List<Product> products = new List<Product>() {
    //TODO: Replace it with the actual products
    new Product() {Name = "Product A"},
    new Product() {Name = "Product B"},
    new Product() {Name = "Product C"}
  };

  // Ask user for the product name
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the product");

  string pname = Console.ReadLine();

  // The product user's looking for
  Product res = SearchRestaurantsByName(pname, products);

  //TODO: change this for required response to user
  if (res != null) 
    Console.WriteLine("The product is found");  
  else 
    Console.WriteLine("The product is not found");  
}
```

Comment: It is still showing an error stating that "Not all code paths  return a value". In which variable the found product must be stored in Main() method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A C# question implies this would have been a perfect situation for using Linq. Writing a multi-line method to do the same thing as a single line of Linq is wasteful and does not permit optimisation. Most of the other answers do the same thing with a lot less code.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: yes, you're quite right: Linq is more concise in this case, but since author of the question is a beginner I think that simple foreach loop is easier for him/her to understand. Just a little modification of the erroneous code.

Comment: Understood, but if they worked for me I would instruct them immediately on how to use simple LINQ queries and stop wasting time :)

Answer (score 3):

```
return products.Where( m => m.Name == ProductsName ).FirstOrDefault();
```

A little explanation to the above code.

**FirstOrDefault** is almost the same as First. The difference is how it handles empty collections. If a collection is empty, it returns the default value for the type. This method simplifies code. In some programs it eliminates exceptions.

In this case it will return null when no product have a matching ProductName

Comment: how is this getting upvotes ? OP is clearly a beginner and probably won't be able to understand this code and this answer also doesn't contain any explanation about it!

Comment: @Selman22 I don't think so. Still have added some explanation. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, this answer definitely needed explaining to an obvious newbie. Also, using `Where` *and* `FirstOrDefault` is pointless. Just use `FirstOrDefault` with a lambda expression (or better yet, `SingleOrDefault`, which is semantically better for this question).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a separate method for that? Use LinQ to find an object by a certain property, like this:

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();
var foundPropduct = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
```

If there is a product found, `foundProduct` will be the result, otherwise it will be `null`.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? This is a valid solution.

Comment: +1: This answer is equally valid (although `SingleOrDefault` is semantically better than `FirstOrDefault` if only a single match at most can be expected in the data).

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
var prod =products.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name == ProductName);

return prod;
```

Your method would be like:

```
public static Product SearchProductsByName(string ProductsName, List<Product> products)

{

            Product pd = products.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name == ProductName);


            return pd;
}
```

In my opinion you don't need to make a seperate method, instead of it use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909919%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: +1: This is the most appropriate answer *if at most a single product name should match*. While the alternative `FirstOrDefault` does the same job `SingleOrdefault` is semantically better when only one match *at most* can be expected.

Answer (score 1):

The compile error you mention is down to you not returning a value *if no match was found*. Even if there is always a match the compiler does not know that, so it has to complain about any code being able to exit without a return value:

### e.g. Your existing function should read:

```
    public static Product SearchProductsByName(string ProductsName, List<Product> products)
    {
        Product pd;
        pd= new Product();
        foreach (Product rs in products)
        {
            if (ProductsName == rs.Name)
            {
                return pd;
            }
        }   
        return null;    // <<< Return a value if nothing was found
    }
```

## However...

...as you are writing in C# is is about time you started using LINQ to your advantage.

Iteration, searching etc are what LINQ was designed for. By using LINQ you write less code and become more productive, with less errors (assuming the standard practice that more lines = more errors):

Your code could simply become:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Product res=new Product();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the product");
    string pname = Console.ReadLine();
    res = products.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name == ProductName);
}
```

The funny `x=>x.Name == ProductName` is called a lambda expression. It is basically like a little function that gets passed each value (as `x`) and returns a boolean result of the comparison `x.Name == ProductName`. Treat the `x` as if it was a C# `this` in your head if that helps.

`SingleOrDefault` simply returns the first item where the lambda expression returns true. If no items match it will return a "default", which for an object is `null`.

There are a number of LINQ methods you can use in this case. `Where(x=>x.Name == ProductName)` would return a collection (actually an iEnumerable) of all matching items. `FirstOrdefault()` does almost exactly the same as `SingleOrDefault`. The only difference being that `SingleOrdefault` implies there is only one match (which is the case with your product data). `FirstOrDefault` implies there may be multiple matches, but you don't care which one comes first.

Basically I strongly recommend you start to learn the benefits of LINQ and stop writing functions to perform trivial single-line query operations.